# Why spring.security.user.name and password don't work with Spring cloud config server used via Spring Boot 2?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, basic-authentication, spring-cloud-config

I am trying to secure my Spring cloud config server. As a first step I followed the tutorials which are pretty simple thing to do. The config server works fine without authorisation. But the problem starts when I want to use a very simple basic authentication. I define my own user and password in properties **spring.security.user.name** and **spring.security.user.password**,but the service doesn't seem to work with those.

When I just leave these properties and I use the default "user" and generated password, then everything is fine. I'm stuck with this for a while now, and trying to resolve.

Here is the important part of my config server **pom.xml** file:

```
<artifactId>tao-elszamolas-config</artifactId>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>tao-elszamolas-config</name>
<description>Some config service</description>

<parent>
    <groupId>com.mycompany.tao</groupId>
    <artifactId>tao-elszamolas</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <relativePath>../pom.xml</relativePath> 
</parent>

<dependencies>
    <!-- Spring Cloud config server -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-config-server</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Spring Cloud Eureka client -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Spring Security -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>spring-milestones</id>
        <name>Spring Milestones</name>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

And this is the config server **application.yml**:

```
server:
  port: 9001

spring:
  application:
    name: config-server
  cloud:
    config:
      server:
        git:
          uri: file://${user.home}/application-config
          clone-on-start: true
  security:
    user:
      name: configUser
      password: configPassword

eureka:  
  client:
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: http://localhost:9002/eureka/
```

The config client is basically the discovery service. (I want to implement a discovery-first model used by other microservices.) Here is important part of **pom.xml** for the config client service (discovery service in my case):

```
<name>tao-elszamolas-discovery</name>
<description>Some service discovery</description>

<parent>
    <groupId>com.mycompany.tao</groupId>
    <artifactId>tao-elszamolas</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <relativePath>../pom.xml</relativePath> 
</parent>

<dependencies>
    <!-- Spring Cloud Netflix Eureka service registry server -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-server</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Spring Cloud config client -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-config-client</artifactId>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>spring-milestones</id>
        <name>Spring Milestones</name>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

And this is the **bootstrap.yml** for the config client service:

```
spring:
  application:
    name: discovery-server
  cloud:
    config:
      name: discovery-server
      uri: http://localhost:9001
      username: configUser
      password: configPassword
```

So, if I remove the user name and password from **application.yml** of config server and I use the default **user** as username, and the generated password in the **bootstrap.yml** of discovery server, then everything works fine.

Does anyone has any idea why the custom username and password is not working?

Any help would be very much appreciated. I may made a very trivial mistake and just don't really recognise it.

Comment: Update this line -> password : {noon}configPassword  @bkk

Comment: I tried this, but did not work out. I'm quite unsure about how should I do this so I tried every possible combinations. But still no success. Only the generated password works out.

Comment: share your repo ...

Comment: Great job with your first question and answer! Welcome and keep it up.

Comment: @JonathanJohx: This piece of software is not in Git. Yet. It will be pushed to GitHub, when I come to the quality what can be shared. :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**UPDATE:**

I debugged the Spring framework a bit. I found some very interesting facts in the latest version of `spring-security-core-5.1.1.RELEASE.jar`, more specifically, in the `InMemoryUserDetailsManager` class.

When the users are created in this class this method is called:

```java
public void createUser(UserDetails user) {
    Assert.isTrue(!userExists(user.getUsername()), "user should not exist");

    users.put(user.getUsername().toLowerCase(), new MutableUser(user));
}
```

The focus should be on this part:

```java
user.getUsername().toLowerCase()
```

because when it tries to update the password for the user, it uses this method:

```java
@Override
public UserDetails updatePassword(UserDetails user, String newPassword) {
    String username = user.getUsername();
    MutableUserDetails mutableUser = this.users.get(username);
    mutableUser.setPassword(newPassword);
    return mutableUser;
}
```

Yes, as you see the `updatePassword` method is not consistent with the rest of the class, because it doesn't convert the `username` to *lowercase*.  So it will never work if you define your user in properties file like this: `configUser`.

After I checked out the Spring source code in Github, I found
this commit:

- [InMemoryUserDetailsManager.updatePassword case-insenstive](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/commit/898d005a53de8ad421d1d705516f5f5000235036)

**Conclusion**:

The problem was the user name and not the password. If you want to get this work, the you have the following options:

1. If you are on `Spring Boot`, use the latest parent version, which is **2.1.1.RELEASE**
2. If you insist on using `spring-security-core-5.1.1.RELEASE.jar`, you should use only lower case usernames.